# Reflecting new field values in option groups

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on a database created by someone else and I'm attempting to clean it up. For SEX, the database creator used an option group for Gender (1 = Male, 2 = Female). I prefer to see the actual value in the table (and in all of my queries/reports), so using a query I created a new SEX field with the values "Male" and "Female."

The problem now, however, is that when you browse the records with the form that's used to enter the data, the option group, even when linked to the new SEX field as a control source, is grayed out as if no data had been entered. This would be a huge data integrity issue that could cause users to accidentally click on the wrong gender and overwrite the field. Is there any way to fix this? I'm assuming the option group doesn't recognize the new SEX field as a control source since it's not a number but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table called tbl_Gender. Have only two columns, one is the genderID, the other genderDescription. So your table will look like.

```
tbl_Gender
genderID    |   genderDescription
------------+--------------------
1           |   Male
2           |   Female
```

Now in your real table drop the column SEX. Now when you need the gender to be displayed, just use.

```
SELECT 
    yourTable.Field1, 
    tbl_Gender.genderDescription
FROM 
    yourTable 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_Gender 
ON 
    yourTable.genderValue = tbl_Gender.genderID;
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What is "Field1" and "genderValue"? And will doing this populate the value in any option groups fields in forms associated with that table?

Comment: Actually I get it now and it works, though I suppose I'll just leave both fields (I'm wary of deleting anything). Does it matter that my genderID is a text field and not a primary key? The genius who created this database decided to make all of the numeric fields text values so it was the only way I could join the tables. Thanks.

Comment: You can change them to numeric via a single update Query.First create a numeric column, which will then have the Numeric value of the Text Column. Then once the update is done you can delete the text column. The PK would be very efficient if it was a number field.